# How to keep automatique and same height of multiple floated left divs with differents contents?

Tags: html, css

What I have is 4 divs on two rows (two on top and two on bottom ) I'm working with `float : left;` everything is (was) right but, for some reasons, imagine the content of one of the div would be bigger than the others (more text on the div on top left) so what happens is that divs will be with higher height the the 3 others, div are not well aligned. (you can see the snippet)

What I have to do is make all divs take the same automatique height of div (or divs) that would take more content (and more height)

Please see my very simple script, (the `<span>` is the "new" content on one (or many) divs, it can appears for example on a invalid input form "invalid email" for example so imagine my 4 divs are : name, surname, age, email and if the age is more than 100 years old, the div (bloc) of age would take the span : invalid age ! so this div would be bigger than others ! how to deal with this height problem please ?)

```css
.content{
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.A, .B, .C, .D{
  width : 45%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top:5px;
}

.span_to_add{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.B, .D{
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="A">
  hello A 
    <span class="span_to_add">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
  </div>
   <div class="B">
  hello B
  </div>
   <div class="C">
  hello C
  </div>
   <div class="D">
  hello D
  </div>



</div>
```

Please any help ?

Comment: To make all divs in **all rows** the same height you will need **javascript**. Flexbox can make each div in a single row the same height but not across multiple "rows".

Comment: Let me cut into short, you want to have all 4 div of same height and width ? even if we increase the text of one div, it should automatically increase height and width ?

Comment: @Manjuboyz yes, increasing height (by adding content) of one of them = keeping the row well aligned (for example : the two divs on top : if i increase the height of the left one, all the "row" will increase the heigh (the div on top right will have same height)

Comment: does it worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are fine using table then here is the code :

```
<table id="maintable" >
<tr>
 <td id=firsttd>hello Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasafsdfdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffdsfdsfdsfdsfaaaaaaa</td>
<td>hello B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hello C</td>
<td>hello D</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#maintable{
background-color:yellow;    
}
td
{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color : red;
 width:50px;
}
#firsttd{
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Fiddle :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/926Ltqt8/)

Comment: Just specify the width of the <td> so that automatically it will fit in to that space along with that row which is "Hello B".